# Mysql query problems (total amount of time)

Tags: mysql, date, time, grafana

I’m stuck..
I have the indicators on my heater connected to a raspberry pi. The pi then put the changed state (on and off) with the time into a mysql database.
Before I’ve used PHP to present the data but I’m now trying  out Grafana. And I cant get the mysql query to present what I want.

I need to know how much time the heater has been activated (0/1) in the specified time range (typically the last 24h). And I need to take into account that the time range may start with ”0”, meaning that the heater has been on the time before that. And the same if it ends with ”1”.
And maybe also the percent of the day where it’s been activated.

Can someone please help me?
I'm looking for a result like this

+-------+--------------+--------------+

| value | secondsOfDay | PercentOfDay |

+-------+--------------+--------------+

| 0     |     28800    |     33.3     |

| 1     |     57600    |     66.6     |

+-------+--------------+--------------+

I've prepared:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/556364a

Thanks!

Comment: Please attach your existing structure (table format, sample data, queries you've tried) to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the required data, you can use the following query:

**NOTE:** Depending on `CURRDATE()` the examples will fail. You can ofc. replace `CURDATE()` with a fixed value like `2018-11-27`;

Explanation:

- The query is joining the table with itself, taking into account, that on/off follows each other (`L.id = R.id -1`)
- The query is selecting Any result, where "on" or "off" is `today`.
- IF `on` was yesterday, the on-time is "corrected" to `00:00:00` of today: `case when L.Time < CURDATE() then CURDATE() else L.Time end as onTime`
- IF the last entry is `on`, the off-time is "corrected" to `00:00:00` of tomorrow: `COALESCE(R.time, CURDATE() + Interval 1 day)` (note: You maybe want to use `NOW()` instead of `CURDATE() + Interval 1 day`, to have the current amount of seconds until "now")
- The Same two methods are used to calculate the running seconds.

Query:

```
SELECT 
  L.playtime_id AS LID,
  R.playtime_id AS RID,
  case when L.Time < CURDATE() then CURDATE() else L.Time end as onTime,
  COALESCE(R.time, CURDATE() + Interval 1 day) AS offTime,
  (  
      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(COALESCE(R.time, CURDATE() + Interval 1 day)) -  
      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(case when L.Time < CURDATE() then CURDATE() else L.Time end)
  ) as RunningSeconds
FROM item0005 as L
LEFT JOIN item0005 AS R 
ON L.playtime_id = R.playtime_id -1

WHERE
  L.`value` = 1 AND
  (
    DATE(L.Time) = CURDATE() OR
    DATE (R.Time) = CURDATE()
  )
;
```

Result Example:

```
 LID    RID     onTime                  offTime                 RunningSeconds
 2      3       2018-11-27T09:00:00Z    2018-11-27T11:26:24Z    8784
 4      5       2018-11-27T11:26:27Z    2018-11-27T11:28:29Z    122
 6      7       2018-11-27T11:29:39Z    2018-11-27T11:39:55Z    616
 8      (null)  2018-11-27T11:50:55Z    2018-11-28T00:00:00Z    43745
```

Example assuming 00:00:00 of tomorrow: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20bc14/1

Example using `NOW()` to count up seconds if the last state is `on`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c6227/1

If you just need the Aggregations out of this, you can use another Surrounding Select and calculate the Percentage by knowing a day has 86400 seconds:

```
SELECT
  SUM(RunningSeconds) AS RunningSeconds,
  SUM(RunningSeconds) / 86400 * 100 AS PercentageRunning
 FROM (
   ...
 ) as temp;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20bc14/5

Comment: This is almost perfect. But I cant cant get the first ontime to be CURDATE() if the first value is 0 (If the first value is 0, then it means that it has been in the time before that). Kinda like the last row if it ends on 1.

Comment: @D_69 this case should be covered as well, except for the VERY FIRST value you'll ever have in the system. (For any consecutive day, it's covered and no longer a problem if it starts with "0"). But since this value should appear ONCE in your systems live-time, I would ignore that.

Comment: I just noticed that there is no ID column. The primary key is the date.
Is there a way to modify for this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c7edd ?

Comment: @D_69 for this approach: No. It relies on the fact that on/off always occures with ids of `n` and `n+1`. If you don't have ids, the output is hard to achieve with mysql. It would be easier to just "fetch" everything of "Today", and post-process the result within your programming language used.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    SELECT VALUE, SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(T2,T1))), 100*SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(T2,T1)))/86400 FROM
(SELECT A.VALUE AS VALUE, COALESCE(B.TIME, TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()-2)) AS T1, A.TIME AS T2
FROM ITEM0005 A
LEFT JOIN ITEM0005 B
ON A.PLAYTIME_ID-1= B.PLAYTIME_ID
WHERE A.VALUE='0'
UNION
SELECT '1' AS VALUE, A.TIME AS T1, COALESCE(B.TIME, TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()-1)) AS T2
FROM ITEM0005 A
LEFT JOIN ITEM0005 B
ON A.PLAYTIME_ID= B.PLAYTIME_ID-1
WHERE A.VALUE='0') C
GROUP BY VALUE;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help as well :)